# form in active_admin display names not id's with has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this two models

```
def School
  attr_accesible :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end

def User
  attr_accesible :name
  has_one :school
end
```

I wanna create a new school in active admin, but when I'm supposed to select a user, i want to show the existing user's names not ids. How can i do this?

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "School" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :user_id # ???
    end
    f.buttons
  end
```

Comment: Your association is PROBABLY wrong. A school should have many users and a user should belong to a school.

Comment: Nothing's wrong, a user is an owner of a school. I want when i create a school in active admin, to select from the users that have no school .

Comment: is the user name unique?

Comment: Nup, but he also has email, which is unique, it's ok if we display the email instad of name

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this: (i hope you have more than one attribute in the School model)

```
<%= form_for(@school), do |f| %>
   <%= f.select :user_email, @users_without_schools %>
   <%= f.submit "Create new school" %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller action where you are rendering this form:

```
@school = School.new
@users_without_schools = User.all.map { |user| user.email if user.school.nil? }
```

And in your create action

```
@user = User.find_by_email(params[:user_email])
```

For the user_mail, create a virtual attribute:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes

So in your case your setter method would be something like:

```
Class School < ActiveRecord::Base

   def user_email=(email)
      user = User.find_by_email(email)
      self.user_id = user.id
   end

end
```

Comment: actually, i need this in active_admin, there i have no controller :( . And the problem is not really, finding out what user doens't have a school, is more about displaying user names instead of their id's, in my form

Comment: Well, i gave you the code how to display their emails. You shouldn't display their names since you said they are not unique. I have never worked with Active_admin to be honest, but i don't understand how your user wouldn't have a controller

Comment: I think is has one, but is not generated, is inside the gem or smth. Actually, i figured id out. And about the unique stuff, it will auto match the id with the name, i ll post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "School" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :user_id, as: :select, collection: User.all
    end
    f.buttons
  end
```

It was not so hard :( .

And in model/user.rb

```
def to_s
  self.first_name + " " + self.last_name 
end
```

Comment: Oh cool, i'm sorry i didn't figure it out myself like that, i was rambling around with all the select options that Rails has, there are many options. What do you get in your dropdown menu? User_id's?
And like this you get all users, but not only the users that have no school.

Comment: like this i get all the users, but with their names, not ids.